# Gedit error: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.plugins.restoretabs' is not installed

Tags: gedit, plugins

I rebooted the computer, after the installation of a new CD drive. Attempted to start gedit from the panel (Cinnamon). The icon wiggled, and a box flashed on the screen, then closed.

I have already searched to find an answer to this problem. I have done the following after that research:

- Uninstalled gedit (and ubuntu-desktop)
- Reboot and install gedit from software center - no joy
- Uninstalled
- Logout and installed ubuntu-desktop from terminal with commands

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
  sudo apt-get build-dep ubuntu-desktop
  ```
- Attempts to start gedit in terminal result in this error:

  ```
  (gedit:23646): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.plugins.restoretabs' is not installed
  ```

The number in the parenthesis changes, but the rest of the message has stayed the same through all attempts to fix the problem.

- I did activate the restore tabs plug-in, a day or two prior to shutting down the computer to install the CD drive.

I did not purge when I uninstalled - would like to keep my settings, if possible. If I can edit a setting file, I need to know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message indicates that the plugin gedit-restore-tabs is not installed.

Go to https://github.com/Quixotix/gedit-restore-tabs and install the plugin

Comment: Have continued researching and found some information under Fedora Forums that relates to the problem. It indicates that there is a bug in the plugin. I went into .local/share/gedit/plugins and found there is a directory named gedit-restore-tabs-master. I created a directory in .local/share/gedit and moved the plugin's directory into it. Now all is well. Looking at the URL provided, it appears that the plugin is for gedit v2 and mine is v3.6.1. Fedora Forums indicates that v2 plugins aren't compatible with v3x. I can live without the plugin, but wonder why the problem showed after reboot...

Comment: Thanks for the github URL, was useful in figuring out that I had the wrong version of the plugin. Would mark the thread as solved, but I don't see a way to do so.

Comment: The link i provided is for gedit version 3+ and therefore compatible with your version 3.6.1

Comment: I see that in the text now, however the instructions use the directory '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/', which I took to mean that it was for version 2.x. A misunderstanding that still resulted in a solution, although one without the plugin available. I do not require the plugin, so it is not a problem. I think that, when gedit plugins gets an update, the plugin will be replaced, since I did not remove the whole package, just one directory of the package.